Saying Shehechiyanu on new glasses
When one purchases a new pair of glasses, does one need to say Shehechiyanu on them like one would on a new suit?
Following that, is it permissible to buy them in the Omer or The Three Weeks, assuming they aren't medically necessary?

What the problem be during the Omer?

From my understanding you say shehechayanu any time you get something new that gives you great joy. If the new glasses will make you really happy then say it

Saying שהחיינו
On the Dirshu site there's an answer by רבי מרדכי הלוי שוורצבורד who decides that since spectacles are worn to correct a medical "issue", one does not say שהחיינו.

המשקפיים הינם כלי עזר רפואי להתמודד עם בעיית ליקוי ראיה, לכן אין לברך עליהם שהחיינו.‏

On the Kipa site there's an answer by הרב שלמה בן אליהו who explains that one theoretically should say שהחיינו but since they are for a medical "issue" the custom is not to say it.

מעיקר הדין היה צריך לברך אם שמחים כמובן.‏
אבל לא נהגו לברך שהחינו על כל פגיעה בבריאות, כי התרופה והמשקפים באו לעולם בעצם בגלל החולשה ופגם הראות  אז איננו מברכים על כך שהחינו.‏

(Unsure if these first 2 answers are identical)
The Etz Chaim site brings an answer by הרב יקותיאל אוהב ציון with various opinions, but he decides that one should say שהחיינו, since one feels joy when buying a new pair.

תשובה בקיצור: כל דבר שהאדם שמח בקנייתו מברך עליו שהחיינו, ואפילו אם רוב האנשים לא שמחים באותו דבר, כיון שהאדם שמח, לא ימנע מלברך שהחיינו על שמחתו, ויש בזה שבח ויקר לכבוד ה’ יתברך, ועל כן גם אדם הזקוק למשקפיים או שינים תותבות וכיו”ב, כיון שעכשיו יש לו הנאה ושמחה, מברך שהחיינו. ‏


נימוקים ומקורות:‏
א. הנה דין ברכת שהחיינו הוא בכל כלי חדש או בגד שהאדם שמח בו, וכבר
כתבנו במקום אחר, שבזמנינו שיש חשיבות לנעליים, אזי יש לברך שהחיינו גם
על נעליים חדשות אם שמח בהם, וכדמוכח בדברי התוס’ בברכות (נט ע”ב) ובלשון
השו”ע (סי’ רכג ס”ו). וכך הורה מרן הגר”ד קוק שליט”א. וכעת אין להרחיב
בזה.‏
ביאור צדדי הספק
ב. ובענין משקפיים יש לשאול, שהרי הצורך במשקפיים הוא מחמת לקות הראיה,
וכל אדם מצד רצונו האישי היה מעדיף שלא להזדקק למשקפיים, רק שבעל כרחו
מפני בעיית הראיה הוא קונה אותם, ואם כן אולי יש לומר שעל דבר כזה לא
מברכים שהחיינו. וזה ברור לכאורה שחרש הקונה מכשיר שמיעה לא מברך
שהחיינו, וגם אם יצפה את המכשיר בזהב טהור, הרי בודאי היה מעדיף להיות
בריא ולשמוע ככל האדם, ובעל כרחו שלא בטובתו הוא קונה מכשיר כדי שיוכל
לשמוע יותר טוב. ואם כן הוא הדין לכאורה במשקפיים.‏
דברי גאון עזינו הגר”ד קוק שליט”א
ג. וגאון עזינו הגר”ד קוק שליט”א אמר לי, שענין זה תלוי לכאורה במחלוקת
רש”י ותוס’ בגדר “מלאכה שאינה צריכה לגופה”, דרש”י בשבת (צג ע”ב) ביאר
שברצונו היה מעדיף שלא תעשה המלאכה, אבל התוס’ לא ניחא להו בפירוש זה,
דסוף סוף השתא ניחא ליה בעל כרחו, שהרי יודע עכשיו שלא יגיע לרצונו בלא
המלאכה, ולכן פירשו התוס’ שאדם העושה מלאכה ואין תכליתו כמו תכליתה
במשכן, זהו גדר מלאכה שאינה צריכה לגופה. הרי לפנינו שנחלקו רש”י ותוס’
אם מתחשבים ברצון המקיף של האדם מה היה רוצה אילו היה הדבר בידו, או
דאזלינן בתר השתא ובאשר הוא שם, ואם עכשיו זהו רצונו, אזי המצב העכשווי
הוא הקובע. ולפי”ז יש לומר דלדברי התוס’ יש לברך שהחיינו, ולדברי רש”י יש
מקום לומר דלא יברך. [כיון שיש לצדד דגדרי מלאכות שבת לחוד, והלכות ברכות
השבח לחוד. ודו”ק].‏


Permissiblity to buy them in the Omer or three weeks
During the Omer the classic Halachic books (Shulchan Aruch, Kitzur and others) do not mention that there's a custom not to buy new clothing or not to say שהחיינו - so there should not be an issue.
During the 3 weeks the custom is not to say שהחיינו and thus, if one decides that buying new glasses warrants a שהחיינו, then one should probably refrain from buying them. If one cannot function without them then CLOR, as one would expect it to be allowed - since we do say שהחיינו under extenuating circumstances.

Some have a minhag to avoid it during sefirah too.

@shmosel - and the Halachic source for that is....?

See the footnotes here: https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/shehechiyanu-during-sefirah/

@shmosel - what I found was the primary source - the R' Yerucham who has 2 pages discussing why we don't say שהחיינו for Sefira. FOR Sefira - not DURING Sefira - and this is pointed out in the footnotes. So the entire discussion is based on a misunderstanding of the R' Yerucham. See it for yourself - רבינו ירוחם נתיב חמישי החלק הרביעי דף ר"ב (page number in the new edition.)

I can't speak to those sources, but the minhag is definitely real and well-established in Chabad. Here's some more discussion: https://asktherav.com/3848-shopping-for-clothing-during-sefirah/

See also טעמי המנהגים תרב, פסקי תשובות תצג, and here, here and here.

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46449&st=&pgnum=310&hilite=
